# Get byte array from texture

Tags: c++, directx-11

Can I get a byte array (ARGB) from `D3D11Texture2D`?
DirectX 11 doesn't have the functions `GetSurfaceLevel` and `LockRect`.

Answer (score 3):

Use Map/Unmap functions on your DeviceContext. This will only work for texture types that support reading.

eg

```
D3D11_MAP eMapType = D3D11_MAP_READ;
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;

pDeviceContext->Map(m_pTexture, 0, eMapType, NULL, &mappedResource);

BYTE* pYourBytes = (BYTE*)mappedResource.pData;
unsigned int uiPitch = mappedResource.RowPitch;

// Do stuff here

pDevice->GetDeviceContext()->Unmap(m_pTexture, 0);
```

If you want to read out the contents of a render texture then you will need to first create a staging texture of the same format as your render texture then copy the render texture to the staging texture using DeviceContext->CopyResource().

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to read back the data of a texture? You hold the data in RAM, then upload it to VRAM. You should still have it in RAM or on disk. AM I missing something?

You may want to look at how it was solved in [DirectX 11 framebuffer capture (C++, no Win32 or D3DX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623787/directx-11-framebuffer-capture-c-no-win32-or-d3dx)

Comment: Perhaps the texture was created by a shader

Comment: I must have the data of the existing texture in RAM in ARGB format. Thanks, I will look your example.

Comment: Right, because creating a texture with a shader and reading it back is such an efficient way to do it. If you would have said, it was created though a frame buffer then... OK But in that case you would have access to it through the framebuffer API.

Comment: If I use the shaders it does not work. Can I resolve this problem? Where can I find the example of framebuffer API?

Comment: This Q&A may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120066/doing-readback-from-direct3d-textures-and-surfaces

Comment: Some functions in this example are deprecated in DirectX 11.