# D3D: How can i get color from a x,y coordinate?

Tags: c++

How can i get color type from x,y coordinate by a D3D full-screen program?

i would like to determine if a x,y point is red 255

thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120066/doing-readback-from-direct3d-textures-and-surfaces

Comment: @dowhilefor no it isn't... but just read D3D API dude, what you want to do is simply read out the frame buffer.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand the meaning, can you give me a sample for only detect color? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not specify DX version, there is only brief step-by-step algorithm

```
1) Render your scene to texture

2) Transfer tetxure back from GPU to CPU

3) Fill data from tetxure to memory buffer

5) Recalculate x, y to match tetxure resolution. Rendering window dimension can be different from DX device resolution (you can render smaller texture to bigger window and vice versa)

4) Do lookup at position [x,y]
```

If you are asking, how to get pixel color from 3rd party DX program, you will have to somehow take "screenshot" of application and search for color in it

Comment: Thanks, i am using d3d8. is there any code sample like your steps?

Comment: Why on earth are you using d3d8? That's 13 years old and a completely unsupported API. At least use dx9, which is still being updated.

Comment: Sorry, it is because my program is old and i don't want to change it to dx9. I have to waste too much times to upgrade it.

Comment: Eh.. in that way I am sorry, I know nothing about DX8. I started with DX9

Comment: Ok, i just convert everything to DX9, could you give me a dx9 sample code? thanks!